# Spark: query dataframe vs join

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Spark 1.5. 
There is a static dataset which may range from some hundred MB to some GB (here I discard the option of broadcasting the dataset - too much memory needed). 
I have a Spark Streaming input which I want to enrich with data from that static dataset, providing a common key (I understand this can be done using transform over the DStream to apply RDD/PairRDD logic). Key cardinality is high, on the thousands.

Here there are the options I can see:

I can make the full join, which I guess it would scale well in terms of memory, however it would pose problems in case of too much data having to flow between nodes. I understand it may pay off to partition both static and input RDDs by the same key.

I am considering though to just having the data loaded in a Dataframe, and go querying it every time from the input. Is this too much of a performance penalty? I think this would not be a proper way to use it unless the stream has low cardinality, right?

Are my assumptions correct? Then, would having the full join with partitioning be the preferred option?